# How do I access the logging object declared in a decorator from within the function it decorates?

Tags: python, logging, scope, decorator

Python 3.6; my overall goal is to stick to the dot separated type of logging hierarchy that Python seems to intend for you to use, and reflect that in the log file.

What I'm seeing is that the decorator I have for entry/exit/timing does exactly that, recording while the log entries for the function being decorated only have the module name instead of `module.function`.

I have a logger declaration at the top of the module containing the function I'm working with, which I assume is what's actually being used in my function, rather than the one in the decorator, the removal of which results in unresolved reference errors galore, so I suspect I don't understand how scope works in that particular case.

Here's the code I have:

Setup.py:

```
def log_wrapper(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger('{0}.{1}'.format(f.__module__, f.__qualname__))
        ts = timeit.default_timer()
        try:
            logger.info('Starting {0}'.format(f.__name__))
            logger.debug('Parameters: {0} and {1}'.format(args, kwargs))
            return f(*args,**kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.exception(ex)
        te = timeit.default_timer()
        tf = round(ts-te, 2)
        logger.info('Ending {0} with a processing time of {1}'.format(f.__name__,
                                                                      '{0} seconds'.format(tf) if tf < 60 else
                                                                      '{0} minutes'.format(str(tf/60))))
    return wrapper
```

Utility.py:

```
from library.setup import log_wrapper
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
[...]
@log_wrapper
def foo(args)
```

And the log when `foo()` is called from another script.  Here, line 1 is logged in the calling script, lines 2 and 3 are logged in the decorator, and 4 is inside `foo()`.

```
2019-04-08 13:45:15 root INFO Running df -hP 
2019-04-08 13:45:15 library.utility.foo INFO Starting foo
2019-04-08 13:45:15 library.utility.foo DEBUG Parameters: () and {}
2019-04-08 13:45:15 library.utility INFO Blah
```

To reiterate, what I'd like is for `foo()` to have access to the `library.utility.foo` logger declared in the decorator and for the lines logged inside `foo()` to reflect the fully qualified name

Comment: I think you're over-complicating things here by trying to create a separate logger object *per-function*.  It is far more common for loggers to be per-class or per-module. There are already logging tokens that resolve to the module name and the (unqualified) function name.

Comment: @larsks If that's the more usual way to create loggers I can certainly go with it, and it _would_ be more straightforward! I think too I had conflated some of those logging tokens in my head, namely that `%(name)s`, `%(module)s`, and `%(funcName)s` were linked.